# Error when trying to put product into cart (tempnam())

Tags: magento2, cart, exception

On my live system (PHP7.1 fcgi, magento 2.2.4, prod mode) I get an error when trying to put a product into cart. The product does not end up in the cart.

Instead I get this error in the `exception.log`:

```
[2018-07-11 12:58:17] main.CRITICAL: Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in /www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend.php on line 203 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in /www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend.php on line 203 at /www/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

I have no idea what this means or how to solve it. The same system on my local dev does not produce this error.

Any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this by explicitly setting 3 tmp folders in my `php.ini`:

```
sys_temp_dir="/absolute/path/to/magento2/var/tmp"
session.save_path="/absolute/path/to/magento2/var/tmp"
session.cookie_path="/absolute/path/to/magento2/var/tmp"
```

It seems also related to the fact that php7.1 creates a notice when a script tries to write to the global /tmp folder. I already tried to suppress notices with `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);` in my index.php but that did not help.

Comment: I was facing the issue while logging in to store front in magento 2 website . Solved it by only changing ->  `;sys_temp_dir="/tmp"` to `sys_temp_dir="/absolute/path/to/magento2/var/tmp"` in php.ini